# Fastest way to generate random number from uniform distribtution python

Tags: python, random, boost, scipy

I need to generate large(1 Million) number of random numbers from a uniform distribution. I did some experiments generating 60K random number from uniform distribution over `[0-999]` using

```
scipy.stats.randint(0,1000).rvs(60000)
```

and it took ~0.6s. Then I tried same thing using boost library

`boost::random::uniform_int_distribution`

and it took ~0.25s. So my question is this- Are there better ways of doing what I want to do using python(libraries)? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `numpy.random.randint`:

```
numpy.random.randint(low=1, high=1001, size=60000)
```

On my trials, this runs about 300 times faster than `scipy.stats.randint`, which is part of a system designed more for generality than speed. (Also, `scipy.stats.randint(0,1000).rvs(60000)` is generating integers from 0 to 999, not 1 to 1000.)

Answer (score 4):

It appears to me that `numpy.random.randint` is significantly faster.

```
%timeit scipy.stats.randint(0,1000).rvs(60000)
59.6 ms ± 956 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit np.random.randint(0, 1000, 60000)
202 µs ± 1.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```