# Generating random integers that are multiples of given integer

Tags: python

I have a random function like this:

```
def rand_int(a, b):
    res = random.random()
    diff = b - a
    res = a + (diff * res)
    return int(res)
```

With this I can get a random number between a and b.

Now I want a random number between a and b that is a multiple of 5 like this:

`rand_int(12,100)` output should be one of: 15, 20, 25, 30 ... 85, 90, 95, 100

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Why not use `random.randrange()`? That is functionally equivalent to your `rand_int`.

Comment: You Don't Need To Capitalise Every Word. It makes your requirement harder to read, but also I'm not clear on the expected output here. What values should be multiplied by 5?

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46454170/fastest-way-to-generate-random-number-from-uniform-distribtution-python)

Comment: @Carcigenicate I Have Something Like this ::   rand_int(15, 150)   and outcome should be 55, 80, 90, 30, 110, ......

Comment: @hossein Post all code in the question, formatted as I did with your other code.

Comment: @hossein: You are supposed to edit your question in response to comments (*"edit"* to the right of *"share"* and to the left of *"reopen"*). [*Stack Overflow* is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115).

Comment: @PeterMortensen FYI, rather than describing where to find the "edit" button, you can use the `[edit]` shorthand to create a direct link like this: [edit]

Comment: To make the question clearer, perhaps post a sample sequence of numbers that this function may return if called repeatedly, say 10 times of `rand_int(107, 189)`.

Comment: What do mean by "multiply of 5"? Are the numbers required to be divisible by 5 - e.g. only 110, 115, 120, 125, 130, 135, 140, ... 185 are valid (for `rand_int(107, 189)`)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes outcome is like you say

Comment: Can you [add that information to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55197635/edit)?

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Thanks, I have now used this in my last comment to make it as easy as possible. But doubt anything will happen. The forum / chat style is probably too ingrained.

Comment: @PeterMortensen have you any idea to help me ??

Comment: @hossein: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

::EDIT::
the question was re-phrased making my original answer wrong.

To get a random number between 12 and 100 but with an output rounded to the nearest 5. Note that `round(12/5)*5` is equal to 10. The original post listed "15" as the first example output.

```
def randInt(a, b):
    return 5*round(random.randint(12,100)/5)
```

Comment: What if a is larger than b?

Comment: I think this would work but im sure there are better ways. `return random.randint(min(a,b),max(a,b))*5` This also doesn't account for a/b being a float.

Comment: For a binary choice, I can't think of a better way tbh

Comment: @J'e no I have this rand_int(12, 100) and outcome should like this :: 15,20, 25,40,50,65,....

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
a,b = 11, 27
k = 5

import random
from math import floor, ceil

random.randrange(k*ceil(a/k),k + (k*floor(b/k)),k) for i in range(c)
```

**Test this by generating 100 numbers with the above expression:**

```
l = [random.randrange(k*ceil(a/k),k + (k*floor(b/k)),k) for i in range(100)]
print (l)
```

**Output:**

> [15, 15, 20, 15, 20, 20, 15, 15, 15, 25, 25, 15, 15, 15, 25, 25, 15,
>   25, 15, 25, 15, 25, 15, 20, 15, 20, 25, 20, 15, 15, 25, 15, 15, 15,
>   15, 20, 15, 15, 25, 25, 25, 25, 15, 20, 20, 15, 25, 20, 25, 15, 15,
>   25, 25, 20, 15, 25, 15, 20, 25, 15, 25, 25, 25, 15, 25, 15, 25, 25,
>   25, 25, 20, 20, 15, 20, 20, 15, 15, 15, 20, 25, 20, 15, 25, 25, 15,
>   20, 20, 20, 15, 15, 20, 25, 15, 25, 20, 20, 25, 25, 15, 25]